# Reindexing - browser window during re-indexing

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, indexing, reindex

1. Does the browser window need to remain open when re-indexing from the admin panel? i.e. once I start the re-index process, what happens if the browser window is closed. I am guessing re-indexing would continue as normal in the background, but can you confirm one way or the other?
2. If that is the case, i.e. re-indexing continues, then how do we know when re-indexing is completed (as we had closed that particular window in which we started the re-indexing process)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It depends when you close your browser ^^

**If the page that is supposed to reindex has been reached** and the reindex process has kicked in, then you can close the browser because **it's the server that handles the reindexing process and not the client.**

**If you close the browser right after clicking the reindex button** then chances are that **the reindexing process has not been trigerred** and thus, the reindexing process will not work.

Regarding the second question, you can use the shell to get the status of each index:

```
php -f shell/indexer.php info
php -f shell/indexer.php --status <indexer>
```